AttributeError: module 'speech_recognition' has no attribute 'Recognizer'
Проблема с библиотекой SpeechRecognition в Python. Устанавливал с помощью комманды: pip install SpeechRecognition
Код выдаёт ошибку:
File "D:\VoiceHelper\VoiceHelper.py", line 14, in command
   r = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'speech_recognition' has no attribute 'Recognizer'

Вот сам код:
import speech_recognition
import os
import sys
import webbrowser


def talk(words):
    print(words)
    os.system("say " + words)

talk("Привет, чем я могу помочь вам?")

def command():
    r = speech_recognition.Recognizer()

    with speech_recognition.Microphone() as source:
        print("Говорите")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        zadanie = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU").lower()
        print("Вы сказали: " + zadanie)
    except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError:
        talk("Я вас не понял")
        zadanie = command()

    return zadanie
def makeSomething(zadanie):
    if 'открыть сайт' in zadanie:
        talk("Уже открываю")
        url = 'https://youtube.com'
        webbrowser.open(url)
    elif 'стоп' in zadanie:
        talk("Да, конечно, без проблем")
        sys.exit()
    elif 'имя' in zadanie:
        talk("Меня зовут Сири")
while True:
    makeSomething(command())


Дополнение
Сейчас начали выскакивать такие ошибки:
File "C:\Users\Егор Арестович\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition_init_.py",
line 80, in init self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "D:\VoiceHelper\VoiceHelper.py",
line 18, in command with Microphone() as source:

File "C:\Users\Егор Арестович\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition_init_.py",
line 111, in get_pyaudio from distutils.version import LooseVersion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\VoiceHelper\VoiceHelper.py",
line 42, in <module> makeSomething(command())


Файл с таким же названием "speech_recognition.py" в своей папке не создавали?

нет, я тоже видел это решение, но файла с таким же именем у меня нет

А сам пакет speech_recognition как ставили? Может это код к другой библиотеке с таким же названием.

Добавьте в вопрос точную команду как вы ставили этот пакет. На всякий случай.

pip install SpeechRecognition

Ну тогда странно. Вроде всё норм.

Я сделала так:
import os
import sys
import webbrowser


from speech_recognition import Recognizer, Microphone, UnknownValueError


def talk(words):
    print(words)
    os.system("say " + words)

talk("Привет, чем я могу помочь вам?")

def command():
    r = Recognizer()

    with Microphone() as source:
        print("Говорите")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        zadanie = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU").lower()
        print("Вы сказали: " + zadanie)
    except UnknownValueError:
        talk("Я вас не понял")
        zadanie = command()
# Далее без изменений

И мне потребовалось установить дополнительно -  pip install pyaudio
Вывод в консоль:
(.venv) PS C:\KWORK> & c:/KWORK/.venv/Scripts/python.exe c:/KWORK/my_test.py

Привет, чем я могу помочь вам?
"say" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
Говорите
(.venv) PS C:\KWORK> 

Для Python версии 3.12+ необходима библиотека setuptools - pip install setuptools

Сейчас начали выскакивать 4 ошибки:

File "C:\Users\Егор Арестович\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition_init_.py", line 80, in init
self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "D:\VoiceHelper\VoiceHelper.py", line 18, in command
with Microphone() as source:

File "C:\Users\Егор Арестович\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition_init_.py", line 111, in get_pyaudio
from distutils.version import LooseVersion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\VoiceHelper\VoiceHelper.py", line 42, in 
makeSomething(command())

А в какой программе вы работаете?

Я просто в PyCharm, может это его приколы попробую поставить Visual Studio Code, когда проверю отпишусь

@Egorarestovitsch если изначально заданный вопрос решён и ответ был полезен, вы можете его принять, для этого нужно поставить зелёную галочку слева от него. Если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его отдельно.

@Egorarestovitsch просто доставьте pip install setuptools - ошибка с нехваткой 'distutils' возникла как раз с версии 3.12

БОЖЕ, СПАСИБО mrgervant, целый день потратил на решение этой проблемы, просто от души спасибо
